# Resize a bitmap in xml android

Tags: android, flutter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:left="70dp"
    android:right="70dp">
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

I'm trying to resize bitmap to work for different screen sizes. The image covers the entire screen vertically. What I want to do is to capture the original image quality by doing wrap_content from both sides. How can I use wrap_content?